# I can't hear iheartradio on my computer. Windows media is fine. Any ideas?

Tags: audio, system-sounds

I've tried the suggestions they give onsite, like clearing the browsing history, cookies, cache, etc.  I've tried to use another server.  I can hear Windows media, but I can't hear anything from iheart.  Anyone have any brilliant ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you check to make sure Adobe Flash is installed? http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

Comment: You don't state which version of Windows you are using, but in Windows 7 volume can be adjusted on a per application basis. Try left-clicking the volume icon in the system tray and then clicking on `Mixer`. This should show you all active applications with sound and their soundlevels.

Comment: Windows 8, Roald.
And I have adobe flash and it's current, Eric.
PLEASE!  Any other ideas???  I miss my iheart!!!

Comment: Windows 8 has the same type volume control (as I remember) where you can set volumes per application.

Comment: Where would I find this Roald?  I've tried the left-click volume before and it didn't seem to make a difference.  I'll try again tonight, thanks.

Comment: No such luck.  Opened the mixer and can't find anything regarding setting volumes on iheart.  I see applications, but iheart isn't there.  Any other ideas???  PLEASE!